# LINQ Contains Based on Property

Tags: .net, linq

Need to check if a list contains an item with a property value of X.

Been using FirstOrDefault and comparing to null:

```
   searchItems.FirstOrDefault(si => si.ID == 99) == null
```

Is there better way to do this?

I cannot get past syntax errors on Contains.  Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) method

```
searchItems.Any(si => si.ID == 99)
```

Answer (score 7):

There are probably a few ways to do this, here's another one:

```
bool any = searchItems.Any(si => si.ID == 99);
```

Comment: what is the relevant difference with the selected answer?